# Shared folder with vagrant cause invisible characters appending

Tags: character, vagrant, nfs, invisible

I have a few invisible characters (�) that appear at the end of a javascript document that cause the "illegal character" error in FF or Chrome. I saw different topics about this error, but nothing works for me, and i can't see anything wrong in my document (displaying invisible characters, open it with a hexadecimal editor). This is just driving me crazy.
I use Vagrant with a nginx web server. The document looks clear in the server too (vi + :set list).

Plus, when I get back a clear document from my Git repository, everything works(normal). But each time I want to edit it (like create a new variable at the top of document), I got this error again.

If someone can helps me, thank you.

Comment: Check that you set the encoding to utf-8 in both the html and your files.

Comment: The encoding is already set to utf-8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you're using Vagrant.. please take a look at your _Vagrantfile and check the way files are written on the VM filesystem.

```
cat ~/.vagrant.d/boxes/[YOUR VM NAME]/include/_Vagrantfile
```

Maybe you are using `config.vm.synced_folder` try to use NFS:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/home/myuser/shared", ".", :nfs => true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Guillaume. The problem was with the shared folder. Since I have activated the nfs I don't have any invisible characters anymore.

Comment: I have tried adding nfs but still no good, is there any other way?

Answer (score 19):

If you're using the VirtualBox provider, then VirtualBox shared folders are the default synced folder type. These synced folders use the VirtualBox shared folder system to sync file changes from the guest to the host and vice versa.

There is a [VirtualBox bug](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/351#issuecomment-1339640) related to sendfile which can result in corrupted or non-updating files. You should deactivate sendfile in any web servers you may be running.

In Nginx:

```
sendfile off;
```

In Apache:

```
EnableSendfile Off
```

See vagrant docs: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/virtualbox.html

Comment: This answer is more related to real origin of a problem. Solution from accepted answer is just escape to another sharing mechanism which is not always accesible (like in my case). Thank you!