# JS charset error in browser

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, character-encoding, vagrant, virtualbox

I've bumped into a weird problem. When I'm editing a `.js` document, I'm getting error "SyntaxError: illegal character".

Here is the part of the document. I've just added `alert(1);` as you can see:

[image: Relevant Part of the Document]

Here is how it shows in my browser (note that these symbols at the end of the document):

[image: How It Shows in My Browser]

About document: charset UTF-8, line breaks CRLF.

I'm using Firefox on Ubuntu. Headers from the local server:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
Content-Length: 56871
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Date: Wed, 10 Feb 2016 15:15:05 GMT
Etag: "6d-de27-c52b5640"
Last-Modified: Wed, 10 Feb 2016 15:05:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
```

I tried to change `Content-Type` to `application/javascript`, tried to edit in different editors, tried to remove BOM -- the same result.

UPD: I don't know why but it works when I reload local server! (I use vagrant with centos installed). I tried to reload just apache - still error.
UPD 2: mime-types for `.js` files on local server are `text/x-c` or `text/x-c++` meanwhile it's `text/plain` on host machine

Comment: Did you copy/paste some code into your JavaScript source, and do so from a web page? Sometimes that can cause stray Unicode invisible characters to be included. You can't see them, but the JavaScript parser does.

Comment: Hi. Yes. I've copied 'alert' code from a web page.

Comment: Well you may want to try deleting that and then typing it back in manually.

Comment: Tried manual typing. The same result.

Comment: It can be hard to get rid of those, but some editors make it easier than others. What line of code is associated with the syntax error? That's a good starting point.

Comment: The last line is showed as containing error in developer's console.

Comment: Right, well those little black things are probably what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution of the problem. I've added `EnableSendfile Off` to my .htaccess. For more information follow [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286790/shared-folder-with-vagrant-cause-invisible-characters-appending)

Answer (score 0):

put comma ',' after  variable order_addresses 
And  if you use ajax call to server do not use the Content type